# Good algorithm to convert timestamp to a shorter alphanumeric representation

Tags: algorithm

What would be a good algorithm for taking a timestamp that contains year, month, day, hour, minute, second and convert it into a 7 digit or less(but consistent) alphanumeric representation. **The alphanumeric representation won't distinguish between upper and lower case letters.**

Comment: There are ~64.47 million combinations of the digits and letters (assuming you're using both uppercase and lowercase). This is less than the number of seconds in 2 years. You're not going to get uniqueness; there will be collisions.

Comment: Does it have to be 6 characters? If not, UUIDs based on timestamp might be a good solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: @wooble: I might need some help here, what's your calculation ? I get something like 56.8 billion combinations ?

Comment: @Wooble.. how? There would be 62^6 = about 52.8 billion combinations right? Should last for more than 1000 years..

Comment: I am confused as to how you come up with 64 million? I seem to get 2 billion. I don't doubt you as my math skills are bad but could you please explain. If my math is right then maybe 7 digits would work?

Comment: Oh, looks like i got beat to it. Though its not reassuring that we have 4 different answers here.

Comment: Well, I asked Wolfram Alpha, apparently badly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's do some maths

You can use 7 alphanumeric digits. Each alphanumeric digit take a value from 36 possible different values (26 letters, 10 decimal digits)
So we have 36^7 different values, that is 78364164096.

Now we compute the number of different values needed to represent a given timestamp in one year.
To simplify things a bit we will allow some values that will never happen (ex: 31th november).

Thus, we have

```
month: 12  -> coded from 0 to 11
day: 31  -> coded from 0 to 30
hour: 24
minute: 60
second: 60
```

which gives use 32140800 different possibilites

We now divide 78364164096 / 32140800  which is ~2438, thus we will give an enumeration of timestamps from 00:00 jan 1 0000 to 23:59 dec 31 2437

The encoding is then

```
X = second + minute*60 + hour*60*60 + 
    day*60*60*24 + month*60*60*24*31 + 
    year*60*60*24*31*12
```

And the decoding is

```
second = X mod 60
minute = (X div 60) mod 60
hour = (X div 60*60) mod 24
day = (X div 60*60*24) mod 31
month = (X div 60*60*24*31) mod 12
year = X div 60*60*24*31*12
```

Let's look at an example:

Suppose you want to encode the date december 20, 1998, 05:33:12
So you would have

```
second: 12
minute: 33
hour: 5
day: 19   -> note that we encode days in the range 0..31
month: 11  -> note that we conde months in the range 0..11
year: 1998
```

So we compute:

```
X = 12 + 33*60 + 5*60*60 + 
        19*60*60*24 + 11*60*60*24*31 + 
        1998*60*60*24*31*12
```

That is, X = 12 + 1980 + 18000 + 1641600 + 29462400 + 64217318400 = 64248442392

And now we decode it

```
second = 64248442392 mod 60  = 12
minute = (64248442392 div 60) mod 60 = 33
hour = (64248442392 div 60*60) mod 24 = 5
day = (64248442392 div 60*60*24) mod 31 = 19
month = (64248442392 div 60*60*24*31) mod 12 = 11
year = 64248442392 div 60*60*24*31*12 = 1998
```

Comment: I am so sorry, my question was not clear enough i will edit it. I don't want to differentiate lower case and upper case. Since that decreases possibilities a lot, i think i will increase to 7 digits if necessary.

Comment: I have to admit i am somewhat confused by your answer. Maybe you could give an example of a timestamp along with its encoding.

Comment: Then i would do a base conversion to get 7 digit alphanumeric??

Comment: @Mike: Yes, you have to do a base conversion (to base 36). For each digit, if it is < 10 you would add 48 (to get '0'..'9'), otherwise from 10..36 you would add 55 (to get 'A'..'Z')

Answer (score 5):

Consider a higher than decimal numeral system. For example, the hexadecimal numeral system is base-16. Let's say in our new numeral system, we have digits 0-9, the lower-case alphabet (a-z) and the upper case alphabet (A-Z). This gives us 62 possible digits, so we can use a base-62 numeral system. Here's some Javascript code to do the conversion -

```
function createConverter() {
    let charRange = (start, end) => Array.from(Array(end-start), 
                                         (v, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + start))

    let digits = charRange(48, 48+10)             // 0 to 9
                   .concat(charRange(97, 97+26))  // a to b
                   .concat(charRange(65, 65+26))  // A to B

    let base = digits.length

    return function(decimal) {
            let result = ""
            while (decimal >= base) {
                result = digits[decimal % base] + result
                decimal = parseInt(decimal / base)
            }
            result = digits[decimal] + result
            return result
        }
}

let convert = createConverter()
convert(parseInt(Date.now() / 1000)) // returns a 6-digit alphanumeric string
```

`charRange` is just a utility arrow function to create a range of characters from ASCII codes

`digits` represents all the valid digits in our numeral system. You can add more valid digits (like special chars) to this list

`base` is the number (in decimal) of available digits

Output encoded in this base-62 numeral system will stay 6 digits long for more than 1,700 years.

EDIT: Realized Date.now() returns timestamp in milliseconds not seconds, so I've updated my answer to reflect that

EDIT(2): changed `var` to `let`

Comment: What about decoding? :)

Comment: Why not use base 16, e.g. new Date().getTime().toString(baseNumber) where baseNumber can be for example 16?

Comment: sure - toString takes a radix value upto 36, so you'll get a slightly longer string if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code for coding integers to short strings along with some considerations in my answer to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345833/dynamically-generate-short-urls-for-a-sql-database/5345920#5345920).

You still have to decide how to map datetimes to integers, but other answers already address that.